# Create Event Manager (Messaging System) in Unity Using delegate and event

Tags: c#, events, delegates

There is a video tutorial on unity official website called:

> [Events: Creating a simple messaging system](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/events-creating-simple-messaging-system).

They create a Event Manager or Messaging System.

I watch it and it was very helpful so I create that system on my game and now  decided to instead of using `UnityEvent` and `UnityAction` use `delegate` and `event` which is better performance and good practice. So here is my code [`StopListen()` function not included yet]:

```
    public class EventManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public delegate void GameEvents();
        public event GameEvents onGameEvent;

        private static EventManager _instance = null;
        public static EventManager Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = FindObjectOfType(typeof(EventManager)) as EventManager;
                }
                if(!_instance)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Put a GameObject with this scrip attach to it on your scene.");
                }
                else
                {
                    _instance.InitializeEventDictionary();
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }

        private Dictionary eventsDictionary;
        void InitializeEventDictionary()
        {
            if (eventsDictionary == null)
                eventsDictionary = new Dictionary();
        }

        public void Listen(string eventName, GameEvents gameEvent)
        {
            GameEvents thisEvent = null;
            if (Instance.eventsDictionary.TryGetValue(eventName, out gameEvent))
            {
                thisEvent += gameEvent;
            }
            else
            {            
                thisEvent = new GameEvents();
                thisEvent += gameEvent;
                Instance.eventsDictionary.Add(eventName, thisEvent);
            }
        }

        public void TriggerEvent(string eventName)
        {
            GameEvents thisEvent;
            if(Instance.eventsDictionary.TryGetValue(eventName, out thisEvent))
                thisEvent.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

In my `Listen()` function this line `thisEvent = new GameEvents();` gets me in trouble and I don't know how to fix it! (Help!) :-)

[PS] :

1. Is `delegate` and `event` have better performance then `UnityEvent` and `UnityAction` ?
2. What more should be or must be add to this code, to make it more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

You must define what should invoked when the delegate is accessed, otherwise if nothing should be done the delegate is not necessary.

Like a lamda:

```
thisEvent = new GameEvents(() => { Console.WriteLine("TODO");});
```

Or a method:

```
thisEvent = new GameEvents(Target);
private void Target()
{
     throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

may be have a look at https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/624575/Delegate-Tutorial-for-Beginners

For execution time, I think best is to make a test and see what performs better.